# Azure DevOps REST API - Create PR from master to release branch - Work Items dont show up

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rest-api

When I manually create a PR from the master branch to a release branch "through the ADO UI", the original WorkItems (from Azure Boards) that were associated with the master merge do show up as shown below:
[image]

But when I use the ADO REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

`curl --location --request POST 'https://dev.azure.com/company/project/_apis/git/repositories/repoid/pullrequests?api-version=6.0' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data-raw '{ "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/master", "targetRefName": "refs/heads/release/R2.8", "title": "A new automated release PR for R2.8" }'`

then the associated WorkItems dont show up on the PR.
[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your code is not correct. The below code works on my side.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/<Project Name>/_apis/git/repositories/<Repo Name>/pullrequests?api-version=6.0' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <PAT>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \

--data-raw '{
    "sourceRefName":"refs/heads/<source branch name>",
    "targetRefName":"refs/heads/<target branch name>",
    "title":"<Pull Request Title>",
    "workItemRefs":[{
        "id":"<workitem id>"
    }]
}'
```

Successful:

[image]

Comment: I assume it’s showing up because you mentioned the item in “workItemRefs”. I do not want to do that.
1. PRs are merged to master with work items associated with it. 
2. When I create a PR from master to release branch to bring all recent updates from master to the release branch I want the work items (originally tagged to master merge) to automatically show up on that release branch PR. This works if PR is manually created but not when done through API